# Download html content of a specific div into DB by providing web page link

Tags: html, asp.net, linq

I have a `TextBox` in my ASP.NET application and a `Button`. What I want is to insert a link into the `TextBox` and click the `Button`. The application should copy a specific div of that page and save it into a local database.

Here is the code:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txt_link" runat="server" CssClass="form-control"></asp:TextBox> 
<asp:Button ID="btn_submit" runat="server" Text="Submit" 
        CssClass="btn btn-info" onclick="btn_submit_Click" />
```

Can somebody please advise me how to do this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Make an HTTP request to the page, use a DOM parser to find the HTML element(s) you want in the response, save that data to a database.  Where are you stuck?

Comment: I am totally blind in what you said. can you please give me code?

Comment: That's not really how Stack Overflow works.  We're not here to write your application for you.  Have you tried *anything*?  Googled any terminology or looked for examples?  For example, a Google search for "C# make HTTP request" finds useful examples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @David for you help. After your suggestion i created this

```
HtmlWeb web = new HtmlWeb();
    HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = web.Load(txt.Text);
    HtmlNode rateNode = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//div[@class='ui-box-body']");
    string rate = rateNode.InnerText;
    lbl.Text = rate;
```